# When attempting to use the gcov, an error occurs: Out of memory

Tags: c++, gcov, lcov

When attempting to use gcov, an error occurs:

> Capturing coverage data from . Found gcov version: 5.4.0 Scanning .
>   for .gcda files ... Found 1 data files in . Processing
>   ./gcov/flat_map.gcda Out of memory!

How can I fix it?
if anything, versions of gcov and g++ are the same (5.4.0), RAM 4 Gb

Comment: buy more RAMs ?

Comment: the 'tag' says `c` but the question references `g++`  one or the other needs to be corrected.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake with the tag. Of course i used c++